# GZip Compression For JQuery Without Server Access

Tags: php, javascript, header, gzip, zlib

all. I am required to build a website with each page under 130kb. I know that JQuery 1.4.4 is ~28kb when it's g-zipped, but it's 77kb minified, which is just too much for this particular assignment. I have already built the entire site using JQuery in one implementation or another on each page, so scrapping it would mean days of wasted time.

With that in mind,

1) Can I add content headers to a javascript file to add "Content-Encoding: gzip" without modifying config files on the server end? I'm uploading them to the university server, but I don't have access to the configuration. From the response header, the server is: Apache/1.3.26 (UnitedLinux) mod_ssl/2.8.10 OpenSSL/0.9.6g PHP/4.2.2 mod_perl/1.27

2) From the phpinfo file, I know that ZLIB compression is enabled, but "zlib.output_compression" is not.

3) I realize this can be done using .htaccess. However, I'd like to do it any other way, if possible, since I don't want the school thinking I'm trying to modify their server configuration.

4) Will XHR's setrequestheader method work here, or is that only good for asynchronous files?

I know this is short notice and all, but my Final presentation is tomorrow, and I'll lose a ton of points if my site is over the size limit. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you use the Google hosted jQuery?

Comment: Are you sure the server doesn't already GZIP static content? It really should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options

1. Use jquery hosted somewhere else
   that supports gzip. The file is here
   that you need to include
   http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js
   This gives you a lot more advantages
   such as parallel downloading of
   files and quicker page load times.
2. Other options is to use PHP code to
       zip the jquery js and return it.
       Here is an example
       http://www.lateralcode.com/gzip-files-with-htaccess-and-php/

Comment: Thank you! This is such a help, and it's not "slow", like I'd incorrectly assumed before.

Answer (score 1):

Use http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js, which is GZIPed.